# GitHubs Process for Initial Commit

Tags: git, dvcs

I started using GitHub this weekend for a new personal project (we also use git at work) and their tutorial has me do the following:

```
$ mkdir ~/Hello-World
$ cd ~/Hello-World
$ git init
$ touch README
```

Then after I add my initial commit I add the origin and then can just push:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/Hello-World.git
$ git push origin master
```

Usually, I have to zip up a new repo, copy it to my server, and then perform a `git clone --bare` in order to start pushing to it.  How is it that they are able to skip this step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repo on GitHub is already a bare one, so you can start pushing directly.
(As illustrated on "[Setting up backup (mirror) repositories on GitHub](https://wincent.com/wiki/Setting_up_backup_%28mirror%29_repositories_on_GitHub)")

More on bare repo in this "[all about "bare" repos -- what, why](http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/bare.html)" documentation.

Comment: Since the GitHub bare repo has no commits in it at first, you can add directly your own history, from your local repo to the bare GitHub repo.

Comment: +1 so just to be sure, also gitolite does the same, is it correct?

Comment: @stivlo: yes, Gitolite does create bare repo (but it will add its own hook in it ;) ): https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/src/gitolite.pm#L227

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to create an empty repository on the server and after that you can push your repo to it.

**UPDATE**: as VonC pointed out the new repository must be bare to do so. I was unaware of that since I use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) to create repositories and I suppose that it creates bare ones.

Configuration example for a gitolite repo:

```
repo    adir/myrepo
        RW+     =   user1
        RW+     =   user2
        R       =   user3
```

So to create a repo with gitolite I just add a configuration like that in conf/gitolite.conf and then commit and push the changes. I edit on my laptop, the push goes to the server and triggers the repo creation. Very comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to zip up the repo and copy it to your server.  Just run `git init --bare` to create the bare repo first on your server and then you could push, just like you can with github.